# how to change color of candlestick based on ajax data in amcharts 4?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4, ohlc

I want to change color of some candlestick on charts based on colors that come as a data from backend, Because I do some calculation in backend, and find some candles different than others. so how can I do that?
here is a code in codepen that changes colors but by using condition related to price (Open,high,low,close) or index of candles but I want change color based on another data that calculated in backend and I send it by other data to front end.

```
series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
  if (target.dataItem) {
    if((target.dataItem.index%2==0)){
       return am4core.color("#000000");  
    }
    else {
      if(chart.data[target.dataItem.index].open > chart.data[target.dataItem.index].close){
        return am4core.color("#00FF00");  
      }else {
        return am4core.color("#FF0000");  
      }
    }
```

https://codepen.io/enriqu3/pen/MWYVEzW

for example assume that backend sends an value of "X" with other data(Open,high,low,close,date,X) and I want to change color of each candle based on that "X" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
if(chart.data[target.dataItem.index].x > y)
        {
            return am4core.color("blue");  
        }
        else 
        {
                if(chart.data[target.dataItem.index].open >chart.data[target.dataItem.index].close) return am4core.color("red");  
        else return am4core.color("green");  
        }
```